# Change of Basis to Upper-Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that every operator T over a finite-dimensional complex $V$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V$.

Is there an procedure to convert a matrix $A$ to upper triangular form, similar to the one to diagonalize shown below?

For a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ that can be diagonalized, there is a simple procedure. Find distinct eigenvalues, find the corresponding eigenvectors. Then $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots \lambda_n$ and $P$ is the corresponding eigenvectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$.

Comment: Yes, if you go through the proof of the theorem, you'll see that it is essentially an iterative procedure.

Comment: That procedure is called Gaussian elimination, and it produces a LUP factorization.

Comment: @ChristopherGadzinski So the change of basis matrix would be product $E_nE_{n-1} ... E_1$ where each $E_i$ denotes one step in the Gaussian elimination algorithm, and $A=E_nE_{n-1} ... E_1 B (E_1)^{-1} (E_2)^{-1} ... (E_{n})^{-1}$, where $B$ is the desired upper triangular matrix?

Comment: What about Schur decomposition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition . Following one of its proof, (without concerning about efficiency) is to find eigenvector of its adjoin, then consider restriction of $T$ on its orthogonal complement, repeat the same procedure then.

Comment: Okay, and the Householder process also converts a matrix into a triangular form. The point is that you only need a field (actually a division ring) to guarantee that a linear operator has an upper-triangular form. No inner product, no algebraic completeness.

Answer (score 1):

As $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}$ space $\chi_A$ has at least one complex root which is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of some eigenvector $v$. Consider a basis for $V$ as $\beta=\{v,w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1}\}$ and the cange of basis $C_{\beta E}$ then:

$$
C_{E\beta} A C_{\beta E}= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & * & \cdots & *\\
0 & & &\\
\vdots & &  M &\\
0 & 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $M$ is the matrix for the restriction $T|_W$ with $W=\langle w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1} \rangle$.

Then apply the same process to $M$ so as to find a basis $\gamma$ of $W$ such that $(C_{\gamma E}MC_{E\gamma})_{i 1} = 0$ for $i\neq 1$ .

Then:

$$
P^{-1}C_{E\beta}AC_{\beta E}P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & * & \cdots & *\\
0 & \mu & * \cdots &*\\
\vdots & 0 &   &\\
\vdots & \vdots & M'\\
0 & 0 &
\end{pmatrix}
$$
 where
$$
 P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 &   &        &   \\
\vdots &   & C_{\gamma E}     \\
0 & \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Iterating this process you will have an upper triangular matrix and the change of basis needed.